# how to extract data from query in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

i want to extract data from a google sheet query

QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1HD5VhfUoCYq3fRcWQJSrkv1vxXEVdNeogho","A32000:Z"),"SELECT SUM(Col10),AVG(Col5) WHERE Col2='"&$B2&"' GROUP BY Col17 LABEL SUM(Col10)'',AVG(Col5)''",0)

I used this google sheet query to extract following data
revenue  voltage
300 46.48
190 44.7
190 46.74
200 45.16
190 47.09
190 45.27
190 47.56
190 46.32
150 45.78
190 46.67
190 44.15
190 46.6
190 45.72
380 45.38
190 45.11

now i want to get voltage where revenue is 200 but withouot using other query
expected answer

revenue   voltage
200        45.16

Comment: Try `=QUERY(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1HD5VhfUoCYq3fRcWQJSrkv1vxXEVdNeogho","A32000:Z"),"SELECT SUM(Col10),AVG(Col5) WHERE Col2='"&$B2&"' GROUP BY Col17 LABEL SUM(Col10)'',AVG(Col5)''",0),"where Col1=200")

Answer (score 0):

You can use another query to filter data based on `revenue`. Try below query.

```
=QUERY(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1HD5VhfUoCYq3fRcWQJSrkv1vxXEVdNeogho","A32000:Z"),"SELECT SUM(Col10),AVG(Col5) WHERE Col2='"&$B2&"' GROUP BY Col17 LABEL SUM(Col10)'',AVG(Col5)''",0),"where Col1=200")
```